# flutter Sorting arraylist by Date

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart, flutter-test, stream-builder

In My streamBuilder I have Array list contains dates having format(dd-MM-yyyy).
I want to arrange the list in ascending order.
**The code I used in StreamBuilder after getting Datasnapshot**

```
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = snap.data.snapshot.value;

              List item = [];
              data.forEach(
                  (index, data) => item.add(
                      {"key": index, ...data}
                      )
              );
              item..sort((a,b)=>a['key'].compareTo(b['key']));
```

**I am expecting result as**
16-06-2020
17-06-2020
18-06-2020
19-06-2020
22-06-2020
04-07-2020

**The result I am getting is**
04-07-2020
16-06-2020
17-06-2020
18-06-2020
19-06-2020
22-06-2020

Comment: What type is `a['key']`? It looks like it is a `String` which explain the weird sorting and not `DateTime`?

Comment: @julemand101 yes it is child value read from Firebase Database. Can you please help me how to sort it in DateTime?

Comment: You need to parse a['key'] and b['key'] to DateTime.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to parse your `String`s to `DateTime`s. Since DateTime `parse()` method won't accept Strings in the format you provided, you can do something like this:

```
List<String> strings = ['04-07-2020', '17-06-2020', '16-06-2020', '19-06-2020', '18-06-2020', '22-06-2020'];
List<DateTime> dateTimes = [];
  
strings.forEach((string) {
  var splitted = string.split('-');
  var day = splitted[0];
  var month = splitted[1];
  var year = splitted[2];
  var formatted = '$year-$month-$day';
  dateTimes.add(DateTime.parse(formatted));
});
  
dateTimes.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
```

Just adapt it for your structure!

Answer (score 0):

Storing the data as Timestamps in Firebase would make it much simpler, then you can sort it by this Timestamp.
If you need the dates formatted as a String (dd-MM-yyyy) you can just parse it to Datetime and use the Intl-Package to convert it to a formatted String.